# select the checkbox of a particular value the corresponding table column should hide

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- when I click the filter on the top right corner menu opens.
- in that menu it has table header values with checkboxes.
- when I select the checkbox of a particular value the corresponding table column should hide.
- so I wrote a click event for that check box but I am not sure how to pass table columns values there and hide it
- I debugged by putting consoles to get the values.
  `const handleColumnHide = event => {
  console.log("event--->", event);
  console.log("event.target.value--->", event.target.value);
  };`
- but I am getting undefined.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet  and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-210lr

```or-tag-here
function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData("Donut", 452, 25.0, 51, 4.9),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Honeycomb", 408, 3.2, 87, 6.5),
  createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData("Jelly Bean", 375, 0.0, 94, 0.0),
  createData("KitKat", 518, 26.0, 65, 7.0),
  createData("Lollipop", 392, 0.2, 98, 0.0),
  createData("Marshmallow", 318, 0, 81, 2.0),
  createData("Nougat", 360, 19.0, 9, 37.0),
  createData("Oreo", 437, 18.0, 63, 4.0)
];

const handleColumnHide = event => {
    console.log("event--->", event);
    console.log("event.target.value--->", event.target.value);
  };

   <Tooltip title="Filter list">
            <IconButton aria-label="filter list">
              <FilterListIcon onClick={handleClick} />
              <Menu
                id="simple-menu"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                keepMounted
                open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                onClose={handleClose}
              >
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={handleColumnHide}
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "select all desserts" }}
                  />
                  Dessert
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={handleColumnHide}
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "select all desserts" }}
                  />
                  Calories
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={handleColumnHide}
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "select all desserts" }}
                  />
                  Fat
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={handleColumnHide}
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "select all desserts" }}
                  />
                  Carbs
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={handleColumnHide}
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "select all desserts" }}
                  />
                  Protein
                </MenuItem>
              </Menu>
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `event.currentTarget` instead of directly using `event`. 
It is part of javascript event optimization.
You can pass a function from the EnhancedTable to EnhancedTableToolbar to handle the hide of columns.
So in EnhancedTable:

```
// initialRows are the raw data you generated
// change to useState here so your component is updated when the rows change
const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(initialRows);


const hideColumns = colsToHide => {
    // filter out the columns
    let resultRows = initialRows.slice().map(row => {
      // construct a new object
      let result = {};
      let keys = Object.keys(initialRows[0]);
      // add in the properties to the new object 
      // only if it's not in the cols to hide
      for (let key of keys) {
        if (!colsToHide .includes(key)) result[key] = row[key];
      }
      return result;
    });
    // TODO: remove the cols to hide from headers as well
    setRows(resultRows);
  };

// pass the hideColumns function as props to EnhancedTableToolbar
<EnhancedTableToolbar
          numSelected={selected.length}
          hideColumns={hideColumns}
        />
```

In EnhancedTableToolbar, change your handleColumnHide:

```
// state to keep the list of columns to hide
const [hideList, setHideList] = React.useState([]);

// when the onChange event of the checkbox happens
// add to hideList if it is checked, otherwise remove from list
// then call the hideColumns function passed from props
const handleColumnHide = (event, isChecked) => {
  if (isChecked) {
    let resultList = hideList.slice();
    resultList.push(event.currentTarget.value);
    setHideList(resultList);
    props.hideColumns(resultList);
  } else {
    // TODO: remove from result list
  }
};

// you need to add a value props to your checkbox
// this value has to match the createData function
<Checkbox
  onChange={handleColumnHide}
  inputProps={{ "aria-label": "select all desserts" }}
  value="name"
/>
```

In codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-v8e9s

It works on the hiding of dessert. To make it fully work, you need to complete the Todos.

Comment: hey I debugged your code, its hard to understand. Can you give comments so that it will help us in understanding

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer. It  would be easier to see.

Comment: hey I integrate dyour code with api, but now none of the columns are hiding...can you update your code here with comments https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-o8wb4

Comment: Hi. In your demo.js L479 you have `let rows = storeRows || initialRows;`
This will not work. Please change it to `const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(storeRows || initialRows);` to use states. Otherwise the component will not update even when you change the rows.

Comment: hey I updated the changes  `const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(storeRows || initialRows);` in the sandbox, but now I am not able to see the api data, can you update directly in the sandbox  codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-o8wb4